# My cursor doesnt show up in half of my images

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse-cursor

In this section of HTML i inserted elements with JavaScript

```
 <div id="carousel-container" class="carousel-box"> 

 </div>
```

I added styles to the elements i inserted and for some reason the pointer I
wanted to use with the images didnt show up, in some of the images
it does show up, in others the pointer only changes when you hover on the lower half of it,
opposed to changing when you hover on any part of the image as intended.

```
.carousel-box{
overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
cursor: pointer;
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

https://github.com/ArturoV6/E-commerce

Comment: It would be helpful if u could share a reproducible code

Comment: https://github.com/ArturoV6/E-commerce

Comment: Please put just enough code into your question so we can see the problem for ourselves See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try adding cursor styles to the images, not on the div

```css
.carousel-box{
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

.images {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```